# Django : Context processors

Tags: python, django, django-context

***What is the mechanics behind context processors in Django?***

I have used them before, but if someone asks me to teach them what context processors are about, I probably could not answer. This is from Django documentation:

> context_processors is a list of dotted Python paths to callables that
>   are used to populate the context when a template is rendered with a
>   request. These callables take a request object as their argument and
>   return a dict of items to be merged into the context.

Can someone elaborate on this. What are context processors exactly ?

Comment: Templates use context. Context processors add stuff to the context used by templates automatically.

Comment: If a callable is defined as a context processor and it returns a value (usually a dict) such as: `{ 'foo': 'bar' }`, then all the templates in the project will have `context['foo'] == 'bar'`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! I feel like it is so much more. Don't you think explanations and examples would be better suited as an answer ? Or I am overthinking this ? because reality is, there is really low documentation on the subject and very few guide on how tom implement this. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: You're overthinking it. It just adds more items to the context.